Astro renders "0" instead of html
For a language switcher if have this condition:
{
    !isArticleLink ? (
        <a
            href={href}
            class:list={[cn(className, { 'border-b-4 border-regalblue pb-2': isActive })]}
            {...props}
        >
            {language}
        </a>
    ) : (
        (
            <a
                href={`/en/blog/${postNL?.data.translation}`}
                class:list={[cn(className, { 'border-b-4 border-regalblue pb-2': isActive })]}
                {...props}
            >
                EN
            </a>
        ) |
        (
            <a
                href={`/nl/blog/${postEN?.data.translation}`}
                class:list={[cn(className, { 'border-b-4 border-regalblue pb-2': isActive })]}
                {...props}
            >
                NL
            </a>
        )
    )
}

Based on whether is a link for a blogarticle or not, it renders a different link.
When isArticleLink is false, works fine, it outputs "NL|EN".
However when isArticleLink is true it outputs "0|0".
I checked the postEN and postNL objects and both refer to the right object, so I don't know what's causing this issue.
Does anyone know what's going on, or have you had the issue in your Astro code?

Does this answer your question? Why "0" is rendered on short-circuit evaluation of `array.length && ...`

@0stone0 there's no .length being used here.

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to render multiple React components in the React.render() function?

yea I see, could still be an int tho, but didn't see the |. Still a dupe/typo imho tho

You're accidentally using the bitwise OR operator (|) between two JSX elements. The bitwise OR of two non-numeric values is 0 ('a' | 'b') === 0. The correct syntax you're looking for is a JSX Fragment:
    <>
        <a
            href={`/en/blog/${postNL?.data.translation}`}
            class:list={[cn(className, { 'border-b-4 border-regalblue pb-2': isActive })]}
            {...props}
        >
            EN
        </a>
        |
        <a
            href={`/nl/blog/${postEN?.data.translation}`}
            class:list={[cn(className, { 'border-b-4 border-regalblue pb-2': isActive })]}
            {...props}
        >
            NL
        </a>
    </>

